# Web host with Maven 2 support?

Tags: maven-2, web-hosting

Does anyone know of a web host that has support for a Maven 2 project?

Edit: I'm looking for a managed shared server to put code on like what wush.net does with Subversion.

Comment: What do you mean by Maven 2 support? What do you expect exactly?

Answer (score 0):

dev.java.net offers both SVN as well as Maven2 repository.